# How can we handle concurrency errors in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

How can we handle concurrency errors in LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Depends what you want to do when a conflict occurs. Is it safe to commit this data, or is it possible that the committed data is of equal importance and needs to be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by setting the modes on each column for how it participates in conflict checking. There are three options: `Always, Never & WhenChanged`

For more info, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399394.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQConcurrency.aspx)

Also an option is using the `ConflictMode` parameter to `SubmitChanges` (one of `ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict or ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict`. If you set it to the former, the commit will throw when complete, but you will have a collection of failed submissions for further processing... see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649/data-conflict-in-linq) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the concurrency conflicts, one should use the try and catch block in the updataion LINQ to catch the "ChangeConflictException". Once you got the exception, loop throuh changeConflicts collection to way of resolving the problem (KeepCurrentValues, OverwriteCurrentValues and KeepChanges). It would be better,if we are checking the concurency check at field level.